# Kinect Openni - I need to filter out random people from the active user

Tags: actionscript-3, kinect, openni

I need major help!!! I am designing a game that will be at a tradeshow which means lots of people walking by. The problem it seems is that once kinect sees you "New user" even if you are just strolling by it seems to kill or mess up the ONISkeletonEvent.USER_TRACKING data when that user is "LOST".

Please if you have any ideas I need them fast! This thing needs to ship end of week.  I thought I could handle this by assigning an activeUserID and filtering based on that but it just doesn't care. When it "LOST USER" it is game over even if that was just someone watching and then moving away.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenNI identifies each user with a unique ID. Each event message comes with a user id which connects the message to a particular user.

Once a user has its skeleton calibrated, you can skip further calibrations for other users, thus limiting the skeleton tracking to the first user who completed the skeleton calibration procedure.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The issue was that I was building a game that would be left running at a tradeshow that people could come up and play, leave and then someone else could play.  Over time you get "ghost" from old players in the data stream with the wrong ID which conflict with your new active player.  My solution was to filter out data that was outside of the "player zone".  This works pretty well but in the end I just reset the experience after the active user exits the player zone.